# Hash needs to be addressed as per user's input

Tags: ruby, hash

I need a hash to involve other hashes, and perform the operation depending on what the user has chosen. Code:

```
    puts "Indicate name of the bank:"
    bank_name = gets.chomp

    puts "Money to invest:"
    money_invested = gets.to_i 

    puts "Indicate time of investment:"
    time_investment = gets.to_i

    bank_one = { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 }
    bank_two = { 30 => 1.0348, 45 => 1.5897, 60 => 1.0987 }
    back_three = { 30 => 1.0489, 45 => 1.5999, 60 => 1.1589 }
    investment_calculation = money_invested * NEWHASHNEEDEDHERE[time_investment]

    puts "Your money is now of $#{investment_calculation}."
```

According to what the user chooses on `bank_name`, the correct hash should be addresed, and thus the operation. I need a "super hash" including this code:

```
    bank_one = { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 }
    bank_two = { 30 => 1.0348, 45 => 1.5897, 60 => 1.0987 }
    back_three = { 30 => 1.0489, 45 => 1.5999, 60 => 1.1589 }
```

And the, this new hash should be addressed in this variable:

```
    investment_calculation = money_invested * NEWHASHNEEDEDHERE[time_investment]
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'hash', and why hashing is going to help. Is it something to do with the interest rates? Also, it looks like your code needs editing: surely 'back_three' should be 'bank_three'.

Comment: Sorry Graham. Yes, it's related to interes rates, that's why I used a hash. But I needed a "superhash" involving certain data. Fortunately, I was able to sort it out. Thanks for catching the spelling typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define hash of hash as shown below, and access it using `[]` operator

```
interest_rates = {
    "bank_one" => { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 },
    "bank_two" => { 30 => 1.0348, 45 => 1.5897, 60 => 1.0987 },
    "bank_three" => { 30 => 1.0489, 45 => 1.5999, 60 => 1.1589 }
}
investment_calculation = money_invested * interest_rates[bank_name][time_investment]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. It worked fantastically.

Comment: @Topa_14 Then a courteous response would be to accept the answer.  That adds to both your reputation and that of the person who took the time to respond.